# Appending to a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to append data from a csv file to an unordered HTML list. My csv file contains two different types of data for the list.. single and grouped as show below:

```
Test Group Name A,Test Link Name 1,Test URL 1
Test Group Name A,Test Link Name 2,Test URL 2
Test Group Name B,Test Link Name 3,Test URL 3
Test Group Name B,Test Link Name 4,Test URL 4
Test Link Name 5,Test URL 5
Test Link Name 6,Test URL 6
```

The end result needs to look like the below:

```
Test Group Name A
        Test Link Name 1,Test URL 1
        Test Link Name 2,Test URL 2
Test Group Name B
        Test Link Name 3,Test URL 3
        Test Link Name 4,Test URL 4
Test Link Name 5,Test URL 5
Test Link Name 6,Test URL 6
```

I can append the single links fine but getting the grouped links out of the csv and into a separate `<ul>` with an `id=""` for each is proving rather tricky. I think I'd need to probably add each group item to its own array or object and then construct the html from those but I can't think how to do it. The code I've created so far looks like the below:

```
var htmlMenu = '';

$.get(csvFileFolder, function( csvFile ) {
    var data = $.csv.toArrays(csvFile);
        for(var row in data) {
            if (data[row].length > 2){
                htmlMenu += '<li><a href="#">'+data[row][0]+'</a><ul><li><a href="'+data[row][1]+'" target="_blank">'+data[row][2]+'</a></li></ul></li>' //I need to be able to add items to a <ul> by group names
               }else{
                htmlMenu += '<li><a href="'+data[row][1]+'" target="_blank">'+data[row][0]+'</a></li>'; //This works fine
               }
            }
    $('#usefulLinks').append(htmlMenu);
});
```

Anyone able to help?

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to group (name, test) pairs in sublists when a group is specified, or add it to the main list if not specified. This should work:

```
// csv set as dummy string to illustrate
var csv = 'Test Group Name A,Test Link Name 1,Test URL 1\nTest Group Name A,Test Link Name 2,Test URL 2\nTest Group Name B,     Test Link Name 3,Test URL 3\nTest Group Name B,Test Link Name 4,Test URL 4\nTest Link Name 5,Test URL 5\nTest Link Name 6,Test URL 6';
var lines = csv.split('\n');
// initialize main list
var mainUl = $('<ul></ul>');
var group;
var id = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    // split lines by comma ommiting space
    row = lines[i].split(/\s*,\s*/g);
    if (row.length === 3) {
        //if belonging to a group
        if (row[0] !== group) {
            group = row[0];

            // create new sub list with unique id
            var subUl = $('<ul id="ul' + id + '"></ul>');

            // add sublist to new list item on main list
            var li = $('<li><h6>' + row[0] + '</h6></li>');
            li.append(subUl);
            li.appendTo(mainUl);
            id += 1;
            // increment id after each subgroup to access each group's ul sequencially
            // as <ul id="ul0">, <ul id="ul1">... with ul preix so it works with
            // with older versions of HTML (where ids cannot start with number)
        }

        // add items to group
        $('<li>' + row[1] + ',' + row[2] + '</li>').appendTo(subUl);
    } else {
        // add li without sub list if 
        // not belonging to group
        var li = $('<li></li>');
        li.text(row[0] + ',' + row[1]);
        mainUl.append(li);
    }
};

// add main list to body
$('body').append(mainUl);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I can more or less see how this is working but I'm stumped at how your appending to subUl if the group already exists when its not defined for that part of the `if` statement. I'm also adding to an existing `<ul></ul>` so where you setup `var mainUl = $('<ul></ul>');` can I change that to `var mainUl = $('<li></li>');`?

Comment: I just tried in jsfiddle and it works fine (with my changes as well)... but when I try in my proper site it returns an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null` Any ideas?

Comment: Another odd question... can I convert mainUl from an object to a string as I think that's what's causing my issue from my above comment. I'm using another jquery library to make my menu and it doesn't appear to like the object.

Comment: mainUi is main list, some of whose li elements contains lists themselves (subUl), it they belong to a group. If the group changes `(row[0] !== group)` then a new sub ul is created and set to the variable subUl, and this becomes the sub list than items get appended to.

Comment: I tested it and it worked on my end. I would imagine you tried JSFiddle and your site in the same browser, so my best guess would be that some other code on your site is interfereing.

Comment: To answer your last question, when pure HTML elements are converted to strings they produce values like `'[object HTMLUListElement]'` gennerally not useful, jQuery objects return similarly useless values. You can use the jQuery .text method to extract the text of the element or .html to get the markup contained within the element. Why is mainUl being converted to a string?

Comment: I may have wrongly infered from the example that all groups were clustered: group a, group a, group b, group b, .... as opposed to group a, group b, group a, group b. The solution I proposed would produce 4 sub Uls for the second case, but is better in that it does not alter the order of the items.

Comment: When using HTML elements(objects) it doesn't work due to an existing library which is used to create the menu system. If I manually add the same exact HTML code created above as a string it works fine. So if I could extract the text of the element I figured it would work.

Comment: In this case it is pretty straight forward. One can simpy do: `elementString = '<ul>' + mainUl.html() + '</ul>'`. For native HTMLElement objects replace `mainUl.html()` with `mainUl.innerHTML`.

Comment: I used `var elementString = mainUl.html();` in the end... I had to also format the `<li></li>` within the groups but it is now working as expected. THANK YOU so much for ALL your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is a solution that clusters the data and orders the groups in the order in which they are encountered. To illustrate I swapped the group names of the 2nd and 3rd rows in the example you gave.

```
    // csv set as dummy string to illustrate (shuffled the list a bit,
            // order encountered is still the same)
    var csv = 'Test Group Name A,Test Link Name 1,Test URL 1\nTest Group Name B,Test Link Name 2,Test URL 2\nTest Group Name A,   Test Link Name 3,Test URL 3\nTest Group Name B,Test Link Name 4,Test URL 4\nTest Link Name 5,Test URL 5\nTest Link Name 6,Test URL 6';
    var lines = csv.split('\n');
    var id = 0;

    // table containing group names as key, member array as value
    var groups = {}; 

    // ungrouped entried go in here
    var ungrouped = [];

    // push new groups to list to keep original order
    var groupOrder = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        // split lines by comma ommiting space
        row = lines[i].split(/\s*,\s*/g);
        if (row.length === 3) {
            // if group property does not exist in object
            // initialize emtpy list
            if (!(row[0] in groups)){
                groups[row[0]] = [];
                groupOrder.push(row[0]);
            }

            // group member text
            text = row[1] + ',' + row[2];

            // add to list groups[<groupname>]
            groups[row[0]].push(text);
        } else {
            // otherwise add to list of ungrouped elements
            ungrouped.push(row.join(','));
        }
    };

    // we have the data clustered, now we gennenrate the HTML
    var mainUl = $('<ul></ul>');
    for (var h = 0; h < groupOrder.length; h++){
        var group = groupOrder[h]; // get group names in order presented
        var mainLi = $('<li><h6>' + group + '</h6></li>');
        var subUl = $('<ul id="ul' + id + '"></ul>');
        for (var i = 0; i < groups[group].length; i++){
            var subLi = $('<li>' + groups[group][i] + '</li>');
            subUl.append(subLi);
        }

        mainLi.append(subUl);
        mainLi.appendTo(mainUl);
    }

    // append the ungrouped entries at the end
    for (var i = 0; i < ungrouped.length; i++) {
        var mainLi = $('<li>' + ungrouped[i] + '</li>');
        mainUl.append(mainLi);
    };

    // add main list to body for illustration or other element
    $('body').append(mainUl);
```